# Create a Console title from string C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I was trying to create a class, which sets the Console title.
My intention was to get rid of "system(title "something")".
Instead i want to use SetConsoleTitle.
My Problem is that i can set a string i know into the title, but i can't use my string variable. This is my code:

```
int title(string Title){
TCHAR szOldTitle[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR szNewTitle[MAX_PATH];
GetConsoleTitle(szOldTitle, MAX_PATH) 
StringCchPrintf(szNewTitle, MAX_PATH, TEXT(Title), szOldTitle);
SetConsoleTitle(szNewTitle);}
```

Anybody as an idea how to set my string Title as the title of my command line?

Comment: Forget `TCHAR` and give winapi functions wide strings. Hint: `std::wstring` is much more natural than arrays and lets you get the C string.

Comment: You say, *"I can't use my string variable"*.  Why not?  what kind of error do you get?

Comment: i get the error "error C2065: 'LTitle' : undeclared identifier"

Comment: `TEXT(foo)` is for string literals (e.g. `TEXT("abc")`), not variables. You'd have to call [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) or some other string encoding conversion routine depending on the type of `TCHAR` and the encoding of the title in its `string`'s bytes. I suggest following @chris's advice and using `std::wstring` with the explicit Unicode API (`SetConsoleTitleW()` and `WCHAR` instead of `TCHAR`).

Comment: could you be so kind an tell we how to use it? I don't get it

Comment: @DVSProductions: You need to learn a little about string encoding first, specifically the difference between an abstract representation of a Unicode string, and an encoded representation (the actual bytes). The W ("wide") version of the Windows APIs expect the bytes to be encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: @Cameron ok, so how do I change my string to UTF-16?

Comment: It depends on what its current encoding is. If you use `std::wstring` everywhere, you can get away without doing any conversions, because `std::wstring` is used to contain UTF-16 encoded strings in the first place (on Windows that is -- the meaning of `wchar_t` (the underlying element type of `std::wstring`) isn't entirely consistent across all platforms). `std::string` doesn't have an implied encoding, because it's really just a string of plain bytes (well, `char`s, technically) -- which could represent any string depending on the encoding, but typically contain plain ASCII or UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it myself :D
Thanks to all the help from everyone.
For everyone who wants to set the console title, like i intended test this code. Works perfectly for me. Up to 5000 times faster than system("title TEXT");

```html
bool Title(int buffersizex){
 color(1, 1, 1, 1);
 COORD top = { 0, 0 };
 HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, top);
 int flr = 177;
 int ln = 179;
 char filler = flr;
 char line = ln;
 int csitze = buffersizex;
 string text = "Buble for sorting Arrays";
 int lenght = csitze - text.length() + 2;
 double free = lenght / 2;
 int print = free;
 int add = csitze - (print * 2 + text.length() + 2);
 for (int z = 0; z < print; z++){ cout << filler; }
 cout << line << text << line;
 for (int z = 0; z < (print + add); z++){ cout << filler; }

 return true;
}
```

I hope this helps everyone.
Do If you don't believe me Run this:

```html
void TitleSpeedtest(int Checknums){
 int starttim;
 int endttim;
 double runnum = Checknums;
 starttim = clock();
 for (int n = 0; n <runnum; n++){
  title(to_string(clock()));  //run my function runnum times
 }
 endttim = clock();
 double complete = endttim - starttim;
 double single = complete / runnum;
 cout << "My function needs for changing the title: " << single << " millis" << endl;
 int starttim2;
 int endttim2;
 starttim2 = clock();
 for (int n = 0; n <runnum; n++){
  system("title %time%");   //run the system version runnum times
 }
 endttim2 = clock();
 double complete2 = endttim2 - starttim2;
 double single2 = complete2 / runnum;
 cout << "The system Function needes for the same: " << single2 << " millis" << endl;
 double result = complete2 / complete;
 cout << "In other Words, the system() function takes: " << result << " times longer than mine"<<endl;
 stringstream titl;
 titl << "ONLY " << result << "TIMES";
 title(titl.str());
 sleep(5000);
 system("pause");
}
```

Comment: PS: This requires a few includes